# Round upto two decimal places, javascript

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I want to round number upto two decimal places in javascript.
I have found many posts on SO saying `.toFixed` method's behavior is unpredictable for different browsers.

And found this solution in many places, that are accepted with no exception

```
Math.round(yournumber * 100 ) / 100
```

But I found correct but some wrong results also from this calculation like

```
Math.round( 1.27532423 * 100 ) / 100  = 1.28 // this seems correct
Math.round( 1.275 * 100 ) / 100       = 1.27 // as I understand it should also 1.28
Math.round( 1.276 * 100 ) / 100       = 1.28
```

Am I missing something or my understanding is not correct?

**Edit**

Just found that

`1.275 * 100` is returning `127.49999999999999` and that is the reason, if it returns `127.5`, it will yield correct result.

But why it is returning this `127.49999999999999` ????

Comment: @scott.korin - Man!! I think you done it. (Please check my edit part) `1.275 * 10 * 10` is returning correct result `127.5` while `1.275 * 100` was not returning correct result. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @scott.korin comment changed

```
Math.round( 1.27532423 * 100 ) / 100
```

to

```
Math.round( 1.27532423 * 10 * 10) / 100 // changed 100 to 10*10
```

and it worked like a charm :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Floating point math is only precise to the [52nd binary place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) (which is about the 16th decimal). While 1.275 should round up to 1.28, 1.01000110011b == 1.274902d correctly rounds down to 1.27.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to go deep down into mathematics :) But just willing to know if there is any function that can always return me the correct result

Comment: But what does 1.275 should return generally 1.27 or 1.28? I mean for calculation

Answer (score 0):

Here is workaround for that problem:

```
Math.round((1.275*100).toFixed(2))/100 // returns 1.28
```

Explanation of the problem can be found in following [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this float number rounding error, I would multiply max precision 10^21 like the following

```
Math.round(1.275*Math.pow(10,21)/Math.pow(10,19))/100 == 1.28
```